# Windows Firewall blocks mounting from linux

Tags: file-sharing, windows-firewall

I'm trying to mount a windows folder (machine1) under linux (machine2).
Computers are in the same private network.

To achieve this I use:

```
mount -t cifs -o user=... PATH_ON_MACHINE1 PATH_ON_MACHINE2
```

I've spent some time on getting only timeouts and it suddenly occurred to me that maybe a firewall is blocking the connection. I turned off the firewall and was able to connect to my shared folder. Unfortunately I cannot leave it like this.

I went to the "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security" window and enabled everything from the group "File and Printer Sharing" however I'm still getting timeouts.

So my question is:
What other services should I enable in order to be able to connect to the shared folder from linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for other people with the same problem.

The service is called: `Netlogon Service/Inbound Rules`.